# Math behind pinching on touch screen devices

Tags: java, android, ios, zooming

I can't find tutorials or help anywhere since I am not quiet sure how to word it but basically I am implemmenting my own pinch function on my Galaxy S4 for a game. The game finds the change in distance between 2 fingers and scales a 2d picture. However, I have trouble understanding the math behind it as to scale the picture *but keep the same position where it is being pinched*.

As of now the scale factor works starting at 1.0f for normal but I don't know by how much to move the position of the camera.

```
Finger fingerA = engine.getHand().getFinger( 0 );
Finger fingerB = engine.getHand().getFinger( 1 );
float dx1 = fingerA.getX()-fingerB.getX();
float dy1 = fingerA.getY()-fingerB.getY();
float currentFingerDistance = (float)Math.sqrt( dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1 );

//Get a ratio change for zoom
float change = currentFingerDistance/lastFingerDistance;
zoom *= change;

//What do I do for the position?
//camX += 
//camY +=
```

The screen coordinates of the fingers are known and so are the dimensions of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, the midpoint between the two fingers is easy to calculate:

```
midX = (fingerA.getX() + fingerB.getX()) / 2;
midY = (fingerA.getY() + fingerB.getY()) / 2;
```

So, assuming I understand your question, I'm thinking you want to center your scaling transform on that point.

Comment: Well yeah that is pretty obvious. That isn't an answer. I think you just restated my question.

Comment: @sgtHale, OK, I guess I didn't understand your question.  Are you writing your own code to decimate an image? or are you calling some Android API?  I don't know android.  If it's somebody else's API, then probably there is some means to create, concatenate, and apply affine transforms.  You'd probably want to concatenate transforms that shift the point of interest to (0,0), scale the image, and then shift (0,0) back to the point of interest.  But like I said, how you do that with Android...  I don't know.

Comment: No it's just a generic self made library. All of the code above is theoretical. You have an object with position and a ratio for its xscale and yscale.

Comment: @sgtHale, I don't know whether anybody uses java.awt.geom.AffineTransform anymore or, whether it is even available on an Android device, but it sounds like you'd want to use something like it.

Answer (score 0):

A pinch has information for zoom, rotating and translating, but you just need information for translation. So, use dx and dy of current and last midpoint and increment camera position.